# React Native FlatList Inside of a Modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to put a FlatList inside of a Modal but the List just spills out of the containers I have given it rather than scrolling. I have tried adding flex and such, but have had no luck getting the List to stay inside the bounds. Any suggestions?

```js
Here is the Modal

const modalContainer = {
flexDirection: 'column',
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
flex: 1,
  };

  const innerContainer = {
alignItems: 'center',
// flex: 1,
height: 130,
backgroundColor: colors.white.white,
borderRadius: borderRadius.sm,
width: 450,
  };

  render() {
    const styles = styleMaker();

    return (
      <View>
        <Modal visible = {this.props.visible}>
          <View style={styles.overlay} />
          <View style = {styles.modalContainer}>
          <View style = {styles.innerContainer}>
            {this.props.children}
          </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked good for me:

Wrap Flatlist with a ScrollView and a View with `onStartShouldSetResponder={(): boolean => true}`

full example:

```
<Modal
   ....>
  <View style={{ height: 300 }}>
    <ScrollView>
      <View onStartShouldSetResponder={(): boolean => true}>
        <FlatList
         ....
          />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Wait, is that allowed? I got a warning by using a Flatlist inside a ScrollView: ```VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.```. Should I ignore that?

Comment: I'm also getting same warning.

Comment: this code solved my problem with a warning though we can ignore it but can you please explain why this behaviour is happening and why we have to wrap it inside scrollview any kind of explanation or resouce would be greatful thank you.

Comment: `VirtualizedLists should never be nested` exist, do not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to put your FlatList inside a View and give that View `flex: 1`, and the flat list will not go outside the parent view.

By giving the view `flex: 1`, that view will take the remaining space vertically and the FlatList will start to stretch until it reaches the end of the bottom of the parent view, and it will scroll instead of going outside.