# React Native - Flatlist not scrolling in custom dropdown

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have Flatlist that doesn't scroll.
I can't find the problem why its not scrolling.

When I'm trying to scroll, It does nothing. It doesn't give me to scroll past the `Produce` item.

It looks like this (I have more items after `Produce`):
[image]

This is my code:

```
const Dropdown: FC<Props> = ({ label, data, onSelect, current, style }) => {
    
        const [dropdownTop, setDropdownTop] = useState(0);
        const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
        const [selected, setSelected] = useState(current);
    
        const DropdownButton = useRef();
    
        const toggleDropdown = (): void => {
            visible ? setVisible(false) : openDropdown();
        };
    
        const openDropdown = (): void => {
            DropdownButton.current.measure((_fx, _fy, _w, h, _px, _py) => {
                setDropdownTop(_py + h - 10);
            });
            setVisible(true);
        };
    
        const renderDropdown = (): ReactElement<any, any> => {
            return (
                <Modal visible={visible} transparent animationType='none'>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.overlay}
                        onPress={() => setVisible(false)}>
    
                        <View style={[styles.dropdown, { top: dropdownTop }]}>
                            <FlatList
                                data={data}
                                renderItem={renderItem}
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                                contentContainerStyle={{
                                    flexGrow: 1,
                                    flex: 1,
                                }}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </Modal>
            )
        };
    
        const renderItem = ({ item }): ReactElement<any, any> => (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => onItemPress(item)}>
                <Text style={{ color: "#616161" }}>{item.label}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    
        const onItemPress = (item): void => {
            setSelected(item);
            onSelect(item);
            setVisible(false);
        };
    
    
    
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                ref={DropdownButton}
                style={[styles.button, style]}
                activeOpacity={0.6}
                onPress={toggleDropdown}>
                {renderDropdown()}
                <Text style={styles.buttonSecondText}>{label}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{(selected && selected.label) || null}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
    
    export default Dropdown
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        item: {
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
            paddingVertical: 10,
            // borderBottomWidth: 1,
            borderWidth: 1,
        },
    
        button: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            elevation: 10,
            width: '100%',
            paddingHorizontal: 13,
            paddingVertical: 13,
            borderRadius: 10,
            zIndex: 1,
        },
    
        buttonSecondText: {
            flex: 2,
            color: '#000',
            textAlign: 'left',
        },
    
        buttonText: {
            flex: 2,
            textAlign: 'right',
            color: '#000',
        },
    
        dropdown: {
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            width: '100%',
            shadowColor: '#000000',
            shadowRadius: 4,
            shadowOffset: { height: 4, width: 0 },
            shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        },
    });
```

I can't understand where is my problem and why its not scrolling.
Maybe its because its inside a `Modal`? I'm first time trying to use `Modal` in React Native

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native FlatList Inside of a Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661666/react-native-flatlist-inside-of-a-modal)

Comment: That didn't help, however I have found that If I'm trying to set top: 100 or more, it will stop the scrolling. For Example: I have top: 50, And I can scroll it on easy, I'm setting in on 150, I can't scroll